# How should we introduce abbreviations in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Making a tag like "EV" , or "ROI" seems the logical decision, but not everyone might know the meaning of everything. However writing "expected-value" and "return-of-investment" on tags seems like an overkill for me. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we should use abbreviations as the main tag, and use the tag merging/synonym capability to merge the long-name version into the abbreviation.

Example: [EV Tag Synonyms](https://poker.stackexchange.com/tags/ev/synonyms)

Comment: oh, I didn't know about this feature, my bad ! Thanks!